# How to enable PHP_IBM_DB2 function?

Tags: php, db2

Here is what I've done so far:

1) I have downloaded php_ibm_db2-1.9.1-5.3-ts-vc9-x86.zip from http://sourceforge.net/projects/db2mc/
2) Copied php_ibm_db2.dll to c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.10/ext
3) edit php.ini and added this script:

```
extension = php_ibm_db2.dll
```

4) edited httpd.conf and added this script

```
LoadModule php5_module "c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.10/php5apache2_2.dll"
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
PHPIniDir "c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.10/"
```

5) restart wampserver

Result: I still have `Call to undefined function db2_pconnect()`. What did I missed?

Comment: have you got any errors in yoru apache_error.log? does `httpd -t` give you any warnings? Are you running 32-bit WampServer.

Comment: Thanks Leonard, I have found some errors in apache logs, it said that my dll does not match with my apache build and cannot load dynamic DLL.

Comment: @LeonardChallis I just gave up using php_ibm_db2.dll, instead I switch in using COM('ADODB.Connection') with IBM Client Access OLE DB provider (IBMDA400).

Comment: possibly a 32bit/64bit incompatibility issue, then?