# Library List is not being used in remote PHP DB2 connection to IBM i

Tags: php, db2, ibm-midrange, db2-400

I've successfully connected to a remote IBM i DB2 database (AS400) from my local Windows PC via PHP.  I'm using the IBM Data Server Client in conjunction with the `db2_*` functions in PHP.  The problem I'm having is that despite my library list being set properly, it is not being used for unqualified table names.  Instead it uses the current user name as the library.  However, when I qualify the table names everything works like a charm.

I've confirmed that my library list is actually changing when I create the connection by querying `QSYS2.LIBRARY_LIST_INFO`.

```
$database = '<database name>';
$user = '<user name>';
$password = '<password';
$port = <port>;

$options['i5_naming'] = DB2_I5_NAMING_ON;
$options['autocommit'] = DB2_AUTOCOMMIT_OFF;
$options['i5_libl'] = 'MYLIB YOURLIB ANYLIB';

$conn = db2_connect($database, $user, $password, $options);

if ($conn) {
    echo "Connection succeeded."; //It succeeds

}
else {
    echo db2_conn_error()." | ".db2_conn_errormsg()."<br />";
    echo "Connection failed.";
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM QSYS2.LIBRARY_LIST_INFO"; 
//Works and proves my library list reflects 
//what I passed in when creating the connection.

//$sql = "SELECT * FROM LIBRARY_LIST_INFO";
//Generates: "42S02 : [IBM][CLI Driver][AS] SQL0204N "<user name>.LIBRARY_LIST_INFO" is an undefined name. SQLSTATE=42704 SQLCODE=-204"
//where <user name> is the username used to connect to the DB.
//It should be using the library list specified when creating the connection though.  
//This holds true for any table from any library including those specified 
//when creating the connection (which includes QSYS2).

$stmt = db2_prepare($conn, $sql);
$result = db2_execute($stmt);
if($result){
    while($row = db2_fetch_assoc($stmt)){
        echo "<pre>";
        var_dump($row);  //In addition to entries for QSYS, QSYS2, QUSRSYS and QHLPSYS I get entries for MYLIB, YOURLIB and ANYLIB.
        echo "</pre>";
    }
}else{
    echo "failed<br />";
    echo db2_stmt_error()." : ".db2_stmt_errormsg()."<br />";
}
```

Has anyone ever run into this while enabling i5_naming when connecting to a remote DB2 server?  I'm not really sure why it wouldn't be using my library list as the PHP manual states "Unqualified files are resolved using the library list for the job." when enabled.  http://php.net/manual/en/function.db2-connect.php

Comment: Are you sure that the library list is changing?  Or is the job that servicing the connection happening to default to the LIBL you want?

Comment: Admittedly I'm not sure how to check the library list via green screen as I'm not sure exactly which job is servicing the PHP request.  However I've checked by querying `QSYS2.LIBRARY_LIST_INFO` which is supposed to return the current jobs library list according to here: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/wikis/home?lang=en#!/wiki/IBM%20i%20Technology%20Updates/page/QSYS2.LIBRARY_LIST_INFO%20view  Technically, when using the `i5_libl` option a call to `qsys2/qcmdexc` is made after the connection has been established according to here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.db2-connect.php

Comment: So I'm pretty sure the call to `qsys2/qcmdexc` is being made properly as I can see any changes I make to the `i5_libl` option reflected in the query of `QSYS2.LIBRARY_LIST_INFO`.

Comment: Please let me know if there is another, more correct way to determine the library list being used.  I'm just not sure how to determine exactly which job is servicing the PHP script since it could be one of many.  Additionally, the way I understand it the job only exists while PHP is being processed, the job is ended once it's served.  So I'm not even sure how to capture that since the page loads in less that a second.  Much appreciation!

Comment: Haven't looked in detail at your code but DB2_I5_NAMING_ON and "FROM QSYS2.LIBRARY_LIST_INFO" should be mutually exclusive. When using 'i5_NAMING', try specifying "FROM QSYS2/LIBRARY_LIST_INFO". I.e., use 'slash' in place of 'dot'.

Comment: @user2338816 Thank you for the reply.  I'm able to query the DB when specifying the library with either `/` or `.`.  However, I'll be more careful and use the `/` when specifying `DB2_I5_NAMING_ON` since it is supposed to be done that way.  The problem I'm having is when I don't specify a library in my query, it is not being qualified using the library list I specified when creating the connection.  `DB2_I5_NAMING_ON` on php.net states that it should.

Comment: So, are you saying that the posted code works? If so, could you edit the question to show an _example that shows the error_? There might be something unrelated to naming. See about querying QIWS/QCUSTCDT since most of us should have that table and could test your code against it.

Comment: I apologize @user2338816 , I thought the accompanied text in conjunction with the code snippet explain the issue well enough, I edited the code snippet to better explain what the issue is as you suggested.  When I don't qualify the table in my query, the error message states the table could not be found in a library with the same name as the connecting user.  Instead, it should be looking in the library list specified when creating the connection.  QSYS2 is in the library list which I'm passing in when creating the connection.

Comment: I would normally expect QSYS2 to be in the _system portion_ of any system's library lists, and an attempt to add it later to cause an error.

Comment: Thank you @user2338816 , I did not mean to say I'm passing QSYS2 into the connection code.  Rather it is part of the results when I execute the query `SELECT * FROM QSYS2.LIBRARY_LIST_INFO`.  Please note that I've had this same exact code running on an IBM i with Zend Server for years now.  Even right now it works as expected when run on the IBM i.  For some reason the remote connection to the DB2 database on the IBM i is not using the library list specified and I don't know why.  Especially since the proper library list is returned when I query `QSYS2.LIBRARY_LIST_INFO`.

Comment: Becoming more clear. But again, what happens if you use "FROM QSYS2/LIBRARY_LIST_INFO" ("/")? It's odd that it works with a "." when you've told the session that it should be "/". Are there exit programs registered for any QIBM_QZDA_* exit points?

Comment: @user2338816 It does not work with the "/", it only works with the ".".  So it looks like somehow both the 'i5_naming' and 'i5_libl' options passed in when creating the connection are not being used.  php.net states "Unqualified files are resolved using either the default library or the current user ID" when the `I5_naming` option is set to `DB2_I5_NAMING_OFF`.  My behavior right now is using the user id.

Comment: But I've proven the library list is actually changing based on what I pass in.  I'm 110% certain the default library list is not what I'm passing in.  I've also printed the `$options` array right before using it to create the connection and it has `i5_naming` set to `DB2_I5_NAMING_OFF` along with the expected values for `i5_libl`.

Comment: What appears not to be working (or not being set somehow) is `DB2_I5_NAMING_ON`. Though you reference it, it's not effective. Most likely, only Zend support can address this.

Comment: It's been a few years since digging into SQL exit points, so I don't recall if any connection settings can be overridden. If any exit programs are configured there, I'll dig back into those to see it that's possible.

Comment: @user2338816 Thank you.  AFAIK there aren't any exit points setup, but I'll double check to be sure.  Also, while it seems you picked up on the mistake, I want to correct myself for anyone else who comes across this.  In my last comment, I meant to say "I've also printed the $options array right before using it to create the connection and it has `i5_naming` set to `DB2_I5_NAMING_ON` along with the expected values for `i5_libl`."

Comment: @user2338816 I checked and there aren't any exit programs setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved this after opening a PMR with IBM.  All I had to do was apply the latest Fix Pack for DB2 Connect Personal Edition.

Suggested Fix Packs for DB2 Connect:

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=71&uid=swg21321001

Basically the DB2 Connect version I had was released prior to 2013.  It was in 2013 IBM added two tier support by adding the `i5_naming` option.  So my DB2 Connect setup was effectively ignoring the option I was passing.  So that explains why the other options still went through.  On the DB side, since it didn't receive a value for `i5_naming` - it remained as the default.